# SharePoint 2010 Custom XSL View Rendering with Jquery and Ratings Field

Tags: sharepoint, xslt, sharepoint-2010

I'm developing a SharePoint 2010 Internet facing web site with FAQ capabilities.

I've got a Custom list containing ID, Title (rennamed to "Question"), Answer and Fileds for Rating.

I would like writing a XSL Stylesheet in order to customize the list view rendering in the following way:

- FAQ Items should be displayed as an accordion, with JQuery
- Each FAQ could be rated by any users.

So, I wrote this XSL :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt js" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:js="urn:custom-javascript" >

<xsl:import href="/_layouts/xsl/main.xsl"/>
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#faqAnswerAccordion').accordion({
                autoHeight: false,
                collapsible: true
            });

        });

    </script>   

    <a id="top"></a>
    <div id="faqAnswerAccordion">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//Row" mode="Item" />
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template mode="Item" match="Row[../../@TemplateType='100']">
    <xsl:param name="Fields" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="Collapse" select="."/>
    <xsl:param name="Position" select="1"/>
    <xsl:param name="Last" select="1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="thisNode" select="."/>

    <h3 id="header_{@ID}">
        <a id="{@ID}" href="#" ><xsl:value-of select="@Title" disable-output-escaping="yes"/></a>
    </h3>
    <div>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Answer" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </p>
        <p>
            Please rate this FAQ: 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$Fields[@Name='AverageRating']" mode="PrintField">
                <xsl:with-param name="thisNode" select="."/>
                <xsl:with-param name="Position" select="$Position"/>
            </xsl:apply-templates>
        </p>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
```

With that stylesheet, the Jquery Accordion is not generated, but rating star are present.

If I replace the following template definition

```
<xsl:template match="/">
```

By

```
<xsl:template match="View">
```

So, Jquery Accordion work fine, but the Rating Stars are not.

Any Ideas ?

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `mode` to `number` or `body`